# React Native CodePush updates not received when integrating into different app

Tags: react-native-code-push

I have two iOS apps:

1. An app that I created as a React Native project using `react-native
   init` and then integrated CodePush following these [instructions](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#getting-started).
2. An existing iOS app that I want to integrate React Native and CodePush into. This app uses the same CodePush deployment key as app #1.

When I push a CodePush update from the CLI, app #1 gets the update but app #2 doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is because CodePush was filtering the update to the app version of app #1. Because app #2 was an existing app, the app version number was much greater than app #1, so it wasn't getting the CodePush updates. The simple fix was to specify a wildcard `targetBinaryVersion` when deploying:

```
code-push release-react my-ios-app ios --targetBinaryVersion *
```

More details about `targetBinaryVersion` [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push/tree/master/cli#target-binary-version-parameter).